# Azure API Management - Import API using Swagger 2.0 spec - schema property on the responses is not considered

Tags: azure, swagger-2.0, azure-api-management, openapi

i would like to ask your help in relation with one issue i am facing. So basically i defined a swagger 2.0 spec for an API, and on the operation's responses i used the schema property in order to reference some definitions for objects that reflect the responses structure. I validated the spec on the Swagger Editor, and it is valid, and also if i generate the client code, using Swagger Codegen, the client app works well consuming the API. Now, the problem is. I went to the Developer Portal and on the API's details page, i checked the API definition (Open API option) and i compared the spec with my original spec that i used to import the API on the API Management service. And i noticed that the schema property is missing, so it is not referencing the schema of the response. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Apparently using the schema property on the responses, according to Swagger 2.0 spec, you can use nested $refs, in order to reference definitions inside each other. But apparently, it is not possible for Azure API Management Service, since it is mentioned as a limitation in the following link: [API Management - API Import restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions).

Anyway, i will try to change my API's spec in order to avoid nested $refs and workaround the issue.

Thanks